# How to change two consecutive values of an array that meet a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to add a dash between even numbers of an array from an input. As it has to compare two consecutive iterations my idea was to use reduce() and combine it with some condition. I'm new to programming so would be nice if solution would be nice and simple so I could understand... :)

I know it doesn't work this way but You get the gist.
 For ex. from "12534487" i'd like to get "12534-4-87".

```js
ar = prompt("numberInput").split("")
ar.map(x => parseInt(x));
ar.addDashToEven();
const addDashtoEven = (a, b) =>
  for (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0) {
    a = a + "-"
  }
```

Comment: please add raw data and the wanted result.

Comment: What should happen to odd numbers? Should they be left alone? So the evens get joined into a dash-separated string, and odds left as a single numeric element?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update to make a [mcve] - instead of _it doesn't work this way but You get the gist._ The for loop is not valid JS

Comment: odds are left alone, yes. for ex. from "12534487" i'd like to get "12534-4-87"

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: `ar`is an array, it does not have a `addDashToEven` method. Also arrow functions are either `=> expression` or `=> { statement }`, as `for`is a statement you need to add brackets. Additionally it is unclear were `a`and `b`should come from. Please improve your code and narrow down one problem, than ask for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close, you can access the previous value by adding parameters to your [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (`index` and `originalArray`)

```js
console.log(
  "12534487".split("")
  .map((val, index, originalArray) => {
    const prev = originalArray[index - 1];
    return prev !== undefined && !(val % 2) && !(prev % 2) ? "-"+val : val;
  })
  .join("")
)
```

Another choice which seems more intuitive is to use regular expressions:

```js
console.log(
  "125343424324443487".replace(/([02468])(?=[02468])/g, '$1-')
)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It does not show what is expected

Comment: Thanks,  was doing it on my phone, will correct it!

Comment: @Siabadaba, they are pretty useful for string manipulation, but their structure and usage can be difficult. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You could split and map with a check and join the array for getting a string.

This approach takes a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the last item by using the actual index and a new variable name.

```
{ [i - 1]: l }
```

```js
var string = '124568',
    result = string
        .split('')
        .map((r, i, { [i - 1]: l }) => (l % 2 === 0 && r % 2 === 0 ? '-' : '') + r)
        .join('');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use any array methods.

```js
const myString = "12534487";
const myArr = myString.split('');

for(let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
  if(myArr[i] % 2 === 0 && myArr[i+1] % 2 === 0){
    myArr[i] = myArr[i] + '-';   
  }
}

console.log(myArr.join(''))
```

Comment: i like this one - thanks :D But why doesn't it add a dash after the second one too...?

Comment: The only two consecutive numbers from this string "12534487" that divide exactly to 2 are 44.

Comment: soo... myArr[i+1] = myArr[i+1] + '-'; is not necessary, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` like so:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 9];

const res = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  if ((a[a.length - 1] % 2 == 0 || typeof a[a.length - 1] === "string") && c % 2 == 0) {
    a[a.length - 1] += "-" + c;
    return a;
  } else {
    a.push(c);
    return a;
  }
}, []);

console.log(res);
```